# ZFS: Why does resilvering go over all disks in a pool rather than only those in the raidz1 vdev?

Tags: solaris, zfs

I'm wondering why Solaris is reporting

```
action: Wait for the resilver to complete.
 scan: resilver in progress since Sun Jul 14 02:42:44 2013
    24.9T scanned out of 39.2T at 54.9M/s, 75h46m to go
    24.9T scanned out of 39.2T at 54.9M/s, 75h46m to go
    908G resilvered, 63.56% done
```

39.2T is the size of the complete pool, which is built from 4 raidz1 vdevs:

```
config:

        NAME                                       STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        volume                                     ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz1-0                                 ONLINE       0     0     0
...
          raidz1-1                                 ONLINE       0     0     0
...
          raidz1-2                                 ONLINE       0     0     0
...
          raidz1-3                                 ONLINE       0     0     0
...
```

and every raidz1 has 7 disks x 2TB.

So, IIUC, the resilvering would have to go over <= 6x2TB to reconstruct the data of a single failed disk. How comes ZFS is scanning over the whole pool? I thought the redundant data needed for resilvering is not stored across multiple raidzs?

Thank you for explanation!

Comment: OS? And snipping the zpool status doesn't help here - it'd be useful to see which drives it is saying are resilvering (or does it say none?). It is hard to build an accurate picture from what you've put in here. Usually you'd be correct - a resilver has to rebuild from the rest of a vdev, not the entire pool. However, the 'resilver' message has to give some sort of indicator of progress, and it may be misleading in how it is indicating progress. One thing to look at it would be 'iostat -xen 1' - IS it equally loaded across _all_ drives, or are the ones in that vdev working harder?

Comment: Solaris 10 8/11. The resilvering is over by now, but I can tell you it  was a disk inside `raidz1-1`. Thank you for the pointer to `iostat`, I will look into it next time I lose a disk. I'll also have to stop nfsd first in order to isolate the resilvering load from the usual load.